# Dúvida teórica - Interface, responsabilidade única

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, interface, solid

## **Apresentação:**

Criei uma classe fotografia.cs essa deverá ser responsável por:

- Calcular o ângulo de visão da lente;
- Receber o zoom da lente (em mm)
- Receber o fator de corte (valor que multiplicado pelo zoom da lente mostra o valor da lente real)
- Dimensoes do sensor da câmera, etc.

Pensei em criar a interface, mais para fins acadêmicos do que práticos.

**Interface**

```
namespace fotografia
{
    public enum _CamerasFabricante { Canon=0, Nikon = 1, Sony = 2 };
    public interface IFotografia
    {
        int CameraFabricante(_CamerasFabricante _value);
        double FatordeCorte { get; set; }
        int ObjetivaMM { get; set; }

        double SensorHmm { get; set; }
        double SensorVmm { get; set; }
        double CalculoAnguloVisaoH();
        double CalculoAnguloVisaoV();
    }
}
```

ai criei a classe para essa interface:

```
using System;

namespace fotografia
{
    internal class fotografia : IFotografia
    {
        public double FatordeCorte { get; set; }

        public int ObjetivaMM { get; set; }

        public int CameraFabricante(_CamerasFabricante _value)
        {
            return (int)_value;
        }

        private double _MMFinalObjetiva()
        {
            return (Convert.ToDouble(ObjetivaMM) * FatordeCorte);
        }

        public double SensorHmm
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private double myVar;

        public double SensorVmm
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value; }
        }

        public double CalculoAnguloVisaoH()
        {
            double fov = SensorHmm / (2 * _MMFinalObjetiva());

            double arctan = 2 * Math.Atan(fov)  * 180.0 / Math.PI;
            return arctan;
        }

        private double CalculoAnguloVisaoV()
        {
            double fov = SensorVmm / (2 * _MMFinalObjetiva());

            double arctan = 2 * Math.Atan(fov) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
            return arctan;
        }
    }
}
```

## **Dúvidas:**

1. Essa classe esta fazendo mais coisas do que deveria? pois cada método realmente faz apenas 1 única coisa, porém a classe fotografia faz tudo em relação a fotografia. Sobre a responsabilidade única esta correto?
2. Implementei a Interface e a classe corretamente?

Estou chamando assim no programa

```
IFotografia ft = new fotografia();
            ft.CameraFabricante(_CamerasFabricante.Canon);
            ft.ObjetivaMM = 50;
            ft.SensorHmm = 22.3;
            ft.FatordeCorte = 1.6;
            var t = ft.CalculoAnguloVisaoH();
```

Comment: Relevante: http://qualityisspeed.blogspot.com.br/2014/08/why-i-dont-teach-solid.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O principio da responsabilidade unica faz parte dos princípios `SOLID` criados por Robert C. Martin como um guia de design para seguir no seu código mas não como uma obrigação.

Retirado da documentação dos princípios:

> No contexto do Principio da Responsabilidade Unica nós definimos responsabilidade como sendo
>   "a razão para mudança". Se você pensar em um ou mais motivos para mudar uma classe, então esta classe tem mais de uma responsabilidade. Isso é dificil de ver algumas vezes.
>   Nós estamos acostumados a pensar em responsabilidades em grupos. Por exemplo considere a seguinte interface de Modem:

```
public interface Modem
{

    public void Dial(string pno);
    public void Hangup();
    public void Send(char c);
    public char Recv();
}
```

> A maioria de nós concordamos que esta interface parece perfeitamente razoável.
>   As quatro funções que ela declara são certamente funções pertencentes a um modem.
>
> De qualquer foram existem duas responsabilidades mostradas aqui. A primeira é o gerenciamento da conexão. A segunda é a comunicação de dados. As funções dial e hangup gerenciam a conexão do modem, enquanto as funções send e recv comunicam dados.
>
> Devem estas duas responsabilidades serem separadas?
>   Isso vai depender de como a aplicação ira mudar.

[Aqui](http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) tem uma descrição mais completa dos princípios.

Logo para responder a este principio você deve ter em mente como seu aplicativo ira mudar.
Se você ira modificar estas coisas:

1. Calcular o ângulo de visão da lente;
2. Receber o zoom da lente (em mm)
3. Receber o fator de corte (valor que multiplicado pelo zoom da lente mostra o valor da lente real)
4. Dimensoes do sensor da câmera, etc.

Então sua classe tem muitas responsabilidades, caso não modifique ela é totalmente compatível com este princípio.

Comment: compreendo e fica ainda mais difícil decidir, por um lado esse software é algo novo, não existente, então ele com certeza irá ter milhares de mudanças, até porque futuramente será open source..(não existe essa solução para prototipagem em C#, acho que nem no Arduino)
Mas em compensação criar uma classe para cada função dessa classe me parece muita coisa! até pq "Receber o zoom da lente" é apenas um get;set; "receber fator de corte", tb..calcular Objetiva real, basicamente é um valor * o outro, acho que não compensa...enfim..difícil..acho que vou deixar tudo junto por enquanto..

Comment: Ele ainda não mudou correto? Então sua interface é compatível com princípio. Espere os novos requisitos surgirem para reavaliar novamente. Pelo pouco que entendo do dominio do problema ( Fotografia ) acredito que estas configuração são gravadas durante a foto e não mudam posteriormente. Então seria de outra classe, quem sabe fotografia, criar estes valores e inserir ele dentro da fotografia. Depois disso estes valores não mudam nunca mais.

Comment: ....Então seria de outra classe, quem classe MaquinaFotografica, ....

Answer (score 3):

Está correto, porém você deveria criar os métodos também na interface, não só as properties.

```
public enum _CamerasFabricante { Canon=0, Nikon = 1, Sony = 2 };
public interface IFotografia
{
    int CameraFabricante(_CamerasFabricante _value);
    double FatordeCorte { get; set; }
    int ObjetivaMM { get; set; }

    double SensorHmm { get; set; }
    double SensorVmm { get; set; }

    double CalculoAnguloVisaoH()
    double CalculoAnguloVisaoV()
}
```

Comment: Tchicotti, realmente já tinha colocado, esqueci de atualizar no post...obrigado.
Porém SensorHmm, SensorVmm são propriedades que só postarei valores, devo colocar get/set?

Comment: mas em algum momento você irá recuperar esses valores ou não?

Comment: Na verdade só funções internas irão recuperar.

Comment: então precisa permitir o get/set

Comment: e responsabilidade única, minha classe não faz muitas coisas? ou ele quer dizer que cada propriedade deve fazer 1 único objetivo?

Comment: cada propriedade já tem sua responsabilidade... uma interface como a sua, visa agregar ou centralizar as responsabilidades em uma classe. então ela está correta, principalmente pelo fato de agregar o que está relacionado a execução da camera... agora se ela também contivesse por exemplo algo relacionado a cadastro de usuarios por exemplo, que saísse do contexto dela, ela estaria errada