# ArrayList x List

Tags: java, array, lista, arraylist, interface

Qual a diferença de declarar `ArrayList` e `List` para listas em `Java`? Quais as vantagens de utilizar um ou o outro?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [Programar para interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101)

A primeira forma é preferível sempre que possível já que ela é mais genérica. Assim se você quiser mudar a implementação, para um `LinkedList` ou uma lista personalizada sua, por exemplo, ainda é possível fazer mantendo a compatibilidade do código.

A regra é que você deve declarar o tipo mais genérico possível. Não que isto precise ser feito sempre, mas sempre que uma mudança possa afetar a compatibilidade. Dependendo de onde é declarado, se for algo bem interno, pode não afetar nada, mas se fizer parte de uma API pública pode afetar.

Isto vale para qualquer tipo, não apenas para interfaces. A preferência por interfaces é ainda mais importante já que melhora o encapsulamento e [desacopla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) o *design*.

Devido ao polimorfismo mesmo que declare da segunda forma você poderá usar o objeto criado em qualquer lugar que aceite um `List`, afinal um `ArrayList` é um `List` sempre.

## Testes

Outra vantagem é que facilita escrever testes desta forma. Se o tipo é mais geral é mais fácil trocar a implementação para uma outra que realize o teste de forma mais apropriada. Usando a interface você facilita o padrão de [inversão de controle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

## Proteção

Quando você declara um parâmetro ou como um membro de uma classe, por exemplo, usando a interface, é uma forma de tornar o método ou o membro mais geral. Quando declara uma variável local é uma forma de se proteger para não usar membros exclusivos da implementação.

Quando você declara a variável com um tipo superior ao da implementação você está dizendo ao compilador que o objeto ali só poderá fazer as operações deste tipo e qualquer tentativa de acessar membros do tipo concreto produzirá um erro mesmo que a operação seja possível.

É claro que usando o tipo mais genérico você fica um pouco limitado. Você não poderá chamar todos os métodos disponíveis na implementação concreta. Por isso é dito que deve usar o tipo mais geral "se possível". Se você precisa destes métodos específicos do tipo mais específico, então tem que usar a segunda forma.

## Comparação de custos

O consumo de memória será equivalente ao do tipo cuja implementação foi usada. Ou seja, no exemplo será o consumo de memória será o necessário para o `ArrayList`. No exemplo nem poderia ser o consumo do `Array` até porque o tipo `Array` não consome memória já que interfaces não possuem estado, portanto não usam memória. Porém como elas não são implementações elas não podem ser usadas para criar objetos.

Por outro lado é provável que a forma usando a interface adicione um leve consumo extra de processamento já que haverá uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). Não é algo importante mas é bom saber que existe este custo. Mas depende do que está comparando.

## Outras listas

Considere também o uso de um tipo `Collection` que é ainda mais geral.

## Generecidade

Uma última nota, esta forma não genérica não é recomendada. Prefira criar listas com tipos definidos, algo como:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/DifferentType.java).

## Conclusão

Resumindo, esta é uma forma de generalização. As vantagens são a **facilidade de manutenção (atualização) de código e de testes**.

Algumas perguntas aqui que podem ser úteis para entender melhor essas coisas:

- [Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101)
- [Dúvida teórica - Interface, responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10313/101)
- [Utilizar muitas interfaces é uma má prática de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23900/101)
- [Interface ou Abstract?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35317/101)
- [Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101)

[Artigo interessante a ser lido](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: marquei essa como certa por ser mais didática e apresentar mais detalhes

Comment: muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento

Comment: Não entendi essa parte: "Uma última nota. Esta forma não genérica não é recomendada." a que forma não genérica está se referindo?

Comment: @Math :D A usada pelo Ricardo, abaixo.

Answer (score 13):

**List** é uma interface. Ela define o comportamento das listas da api de collections.

**ArrayList** é um tipo de implementação dessa lista, assim como `LinkedList` também é uma implementação de `List`.

Quando você define desta forma:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

Você só pode chamar métodos e membros que pertencem a `List`. Se você defini-lo como:

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
```

Você vai ser capaz de chamar métodos específicos `ArrayList` e membros específicos uso `ArrayList` além daquelas herdadas da Lista.

Link para resposta em inglês: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903145/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-arraylist)

Texto da *Oracle* com as implementações de `List`: [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html)

Comment: Então quando eu utilizo List eu estou utilizando menos memoria do que um ArrayList ?

Comment: Julgo que sim, já que é provável que ArrayList tenha atributos próprios, (julgo também que a economia seja ínfima).

Comment: Mas então qual a real vantagem de declarar um List no lugar de um ArrayList ?

Comment: pode não ser uma vantagem real, mas você pode ter um método que recebe como parâmetro um List, então seria possivel você passar um ArrayList e LinkedList para este método.