# Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, interface, princípios-de-programação

Quais são os principais motivos (na prática) que levam desenvolvedores a aplicar a prática de desenvolver voltado para interface e não para implementação?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Porque interfaces são apenas contratos do que o objeto tem ou é capaz de fazer. Então você pode usar qualquer objeto desde que o contrato esteja garantido.

Tendo apenas o contrato você pode obter melhor:

- Manutibilidade - alterações ficam mais isoladas, não precisa mudar tudo que aceitava uma classe concreta para aceitar outra necessária. Certos detalhes deixam de ser importantes e é possível mudar a implementação sem quebrar a aplicação.
- Extensibilidade - Permite que novas implementações sejam feitas sem alterar tudo que esperava determinado objeto, então certos comportamentos se tornam mais genéricos podendo manipular objetos que ele desconhece desde que contenha o contrato esperado.
- Testabilidade - é fácil substituir um objeto real de produção por um falso que facilite o teste.

Com a interface é uma das formas possíveis de reduzir o [acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Ela ajuda no encapsulamento e abstração que é mais do que ter alguns membros privados. Priorizando o uso da interface o código diz claramente só o que ele precisa ali e as linguagens costumam impedir o acesso a outros membros não presentes na interface declarada mesmo que você saiba que estes membros existam no objeto.

Em alguns casos usar interface é o mesmo que usar classes abstratas.

[Há uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101) que mostra na prática como é importante ser o mais genérico possível no tipo de objeto que se deseja e o mais específico possível no que se deseja fazer com este objeto, quando usa a interface, e esta está definida corretamente, você está dizendo que só fará algo ali que a interface permite, mesmo que o objeto como um todo permita mais.

Isto facilita vários [padrões de projeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), especialmente a [injeção de dependência e inversão de controle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).