# Em OOP, uma interface pode ter atributos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, interface

É possível uma interface possuir atributos? Se não for possível, por que não pode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Uma interface é uma "classe puramente abstrata", que somente **especifica** um tipo mas não o **concretiza**. Quando falamos em "atributo" em OOP normalmente estamos nos referindo a um campo concreto - uma posição de memória por assim dizer - o que se trata de um detalhe de implementação (Nota: [definição controversa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101), mas usada equivocadamente em todo lugar, então vou usar o termo "campo" e não atributo).

Contudo, se imaginarmos "campo" como "algo que uma classe precisa ter" - tipo, uma data precisa ter ano, mês e dia, mas não importa como isso está representado em memória - então seria sim possível que um campo fosse parte da especificação de um tipo. Que eu saiba, nenhuma das linguagens OOP que trabalham com o conceito de "interface" permitem isso (no máximo você pode ter *getters* e *setters* como parte da interface), mas é uma possibilidade, não sei como funcionaria na prática.

Comment: +1 pela definição de 'interface como contrato'.

Comment: @mgisonbr, a sua resposta está de acordo com o que foi perguntado. Apenas não concordo no momento que você fala "Uma interface é uma 'classe puramente abstrata' ". Não faria essa acossiação pois uma interface na verdade é um contrato, é um comportamento que uma classe deve seguir e todos os métodos que a interface declarar devem obrigatóriamente ser implementados.

Comment: Já A classe abstrata é um tipo de classe que somente pode ser herdada e não instanciada, de certa forma pode se  dizer que este tipo de classe é uma classe conceitual que pode                 definir funcionalidades para que as suas subclasses possam implementa-las de forma não obrigatória.

Comment: @LuãGovindaMendesSouza Qual a diferença disso que você falou pra uma classe puramente abstrata? Cada método abstrato numa classe abstrata representa um contrato, mas ela também pode ter métodos concretos e/ou atributos. Elimine os métodos concretos e os atributos, e temos uma interface. Só não é a mesma coisa porque se pode implementar mais de uma interface - mas não herdar de mais de uma classe - mas me parece próximo o bastante para fins de comparação.

Comment: (Nota: Falei pensando em Java, outras linguagens podem permitir sim herança múltipla. E já que toquei nesse ponto, interfaces no Java 8 também podem ter *default methods*, que também definem "funcionalidades para que as suas subclasses possam implementa-las de forma não obrigatória". Parece bem similar pro meu gosto...).

Answer (score 15):

Antes vamos estabelecer o termo correto: [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Em geral, não. Mas nada impede que uma linguagem determine que pode. Provavelmente ela deixaria de ser exatamente uma interface, ainda que mantivesse o nome. De fato algumas linguagens fizeram isto (Java, C#, Kotlin, Swift)

Dito isto, é possível ter linguagens que podem quase ter isto e de forma correta.

C#, por exemplo pode ter propriedades. Propriedade nada mais são que um par de métodos (*getter* e *setter*) e que possuem um campo (termo geral usado) suportando seu valor. Note que no fundo o campo só existirá na classe onde a interface for implementada, ele não existirá na interface.

Sei que Ruby tem algo semelhante.

E concordo com a resposta do mbigsonbr. Se formos falar de campos como um termo conceitual que indica uma característica que a classe deve ter, é possível colocar na interface alguma forma que indique isto, ainda que não tenha um mecanismo nela que coloque uma variável para guardar este estado.

Por exemplo, em Java é possível indicar isto fazendo

```
interface Tax {
    BigIntenger getTax();
    void setTax(BigInteger tax);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Interface/GetterSetter.java).

Aí é problema de quem for implementar esta interface na classe concreta como vai guardar o dado e como os métodos funcionarão.

Não pode porque interface é apenas um contrato, não é para ter detalhamento de como cada coisa deva funcionar. Quem for implementar isto na classe pode escolher uma outra forma de armazenar o dado.

Aí vale rever a outra pergunta [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101). Fazendo isto deixa mais flexível. É preferível dizer apenas **o que** precisa fazer e não **como** precisa fazer. Assim dá para intercambiar mais facilmente os componentes. Se houvesse o detalhe de implementação dentro da interface, ela seria menos flexível em como ela pode trabalhar. Note que no exemplo acima o tipo `BigInteger` foi usado no contrato. Nada impede que o o tipo efetivamente guardado seja de outro tipo que seja mais interessante em determinada situação. percebeu a flexibilidade? Dá para usar a criatividade aí.

Comment: +1 pelo esclarecimento (que muitos desenvolvedores parecem ignorar) a respeito da implementação de setters e getters.