# Interface em Java

Tags: java, interface

Sou iniciante em Java e estou com algumas dúvidas sobre interfaces, gostaria de saber se alguém pode me explicar a parte teórica de interfaces, se alguém tiver um exemplo simples Interface, agradeço.

Comment: https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/interfaces/#10-1-aumentando-nosso-exemplo

Comment: Um bom começo, alem do link que o @BrumazziD.B. já indicou, é olhar a tag [tag:interface+java]  também.

Comment: Cara, uma interface é um tipo de referência em Java, é semelhante a uma classe, é uma coleção de métodos abstratos. Não sendo instanciável, ela serve como um molde para que outras classes a herdem e implementem seus métodos abst. da maneira especifica em que cada uma vai se comportar. Tem mais coisa além disso, mas já da uma clareada!

Comment: Obrigado galera.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/101