# Instanciar um objeto pela interface e acessar métodos não presentes nela

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface, declaração-de-variável

Tenho a seguinte interface:

```
interface something {
    void doSomething();
}
```

E tenho uma classe que implementa essa interface e adiciona outro método que não contém na interface:

```
public class Whatever implements something {

    //Método da interface
    public void doSomething() {
       System.out.println("Do something !");
    }     

    public void didSomething() {
       System.out.println("Did something !");
    }
}
```

Procurando seguir a proposta de programar para uma interface e não para uma implementação, o código abaixo estaria correto:

```
   public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] arguments) {
          Something s = new Whatever();
          s.doSomething();
       }
   }
```

Agora, se eu quiser chamar o método especializado da classe `Whatever`, a partir do tipo de variável (interface), não consigo, pois o método não é encontrado.

```
   public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] arguments) {
          Something s = new Whatever();
          s.doSomething();
          //Erro, pois não acha o método
          s.didSomething();
       }
   }
```

As duas únicas formas que achei foram, colocando o tipo de variável (classe) ou mantendo o tipo de variável (interface) mas fazendo um cast na chamada do método:

```
   public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] arguments) {

          //Isso...
          Something s = new Whatever();
          s.doSomething();
          ((Whatever) s).didSomething();

          //Ou isso...
          Whatever w = new Whatever(); 
          w.doSomething();
          w.didSomething();
       }
   }
```

1) Existe um outro modo para o acesso a este método especializado na classe concreta que implementa a interface ? Pensei em usar um `instanceof` para verificar se a variável é de um determinado tipo, mas não me parece uma boa escolha ficar colocando testes para verificar se a classe suporta determinado método.

2) Caso não exista, qual seria a vantagem de se utilizar classes que tem métodos especializados mas que implementam interfaces, já que o tipo de variável teria que ser de uma classe concreta e não de uma interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você não entendeu o que é programar para interface. Acredito que está achando que é uma regra que criaram e deve seguir. Não é. É algo para entender porque existe isso e fazer quando necessário.

Você deve declarar uma variável como a interface se você precisa **apenas** do que está na interface. Se precisa do que está na classe concreta então deve declarar a classe concreta.

Fazer um *cast* ou outra coisa, é adotar um erro para consertar o primeiro erro cometido.

Interfaces devem ser usadas para segregar responsabilidades. Você [programa para interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101) para que aquilo que receberá o objeto só possa acessar o que está naquele tipo. É proposital que não deixa acessar os demais membros do objeto concreto. Se usou a interface, aquele código desconhece o que não está na interface.

Ainda quer chamar `didSomething()` e ser por uma interface? Tem duas possibilidades:

- Crie uma nova interface com esse método e aí poderá declarar a variável com o tipo da interface, acessar o método desejado, e estará programando para a interface. Considero este o mais adequado, mas pode não ser, em um exemplo abstrato assim, tudo é possível;
- Coloque o método na interface já existente e poderá acessá-lo. Pode não ser o que deseja, mas é uma possibilidade. Eu não sei o que deseja, os nomes usados não indicam o  que deveria ser.

Na verdade apesar de ser útil para ver o funcionamento, programar para interface em algo simples assim não tem utilidade prática alguma. É útil usar esta técnica quando tem sistemas complexos, que precisarão de manutenção e flexibilidade para trocar a implementação sem ter que trocar o contrato.

```
interface Something {
    void doSomething();
}

interface Otherthing {
    void doOtherthing();
}

class Whatever implements Something, Otherthing {
    public void doSomething() {
       System.out.println("Do something !");
    }     
    public void doOtherthing() {
       System.out.println("Do otherthing !");
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Something s = new Whatever();
        s.doSomething();
        Otherthing w = new Whatever(); 
        w.doOtherthing();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/nbeY60). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/umtdsogm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Interface/Segregation.java).

Comment: Na verdade essa pergunta se deve a preocupação de que uma interface não esteja bem definida na sua criação. Um exemplo: Posso ter criado uma interface e depois de um algum tempo ter notado que ela deveria ter mais um método. O que fazer como todos aqueles que usam a minha interface ? Afinal, todos eles teriam que modificar suas classes. Por isso, pensei nesta alternativa (equivocada) quando o ideal (eu acho) seria criar uma nova interface com os novos métodos e deixar a cargo das outras pessoas a decisão de usarem ou não a nova interface.

Comment: @RobertoCoelho é basicamente isto, mesmo, quando se erra no planejamento, nem sempre é fácil resolver depois.

Comment: @bigdown refinando mais o assunto: uma boa prática para corrigir o erro e forçar o uso da nova interface em versões futuras, seria usar "@Deprecated" na interface mal planejada...

Answer (score 5):

Uma interface é um contrato, onde ambas as partes, a classe que implementa e a classe que utiliza, conhecem as "regras" do contrato.

Qual o sentido de criar uma "regra" que não esteja no contrato, no seu caso, o método **didSomething**?

Todos os métodos que serão públicos deveriam estar na interface, pois a classe que irá utilizar deve saber exatamente **tudo** o que ela pode usar, senão não há sentido em existir uma interface.

Respondendo sua pergunta, ao criar um objeto do tipo de uma interface, você só conseguirá usar o que está exposto na interface, o código não vai "enxergar" outros métodos não especificados na interface, a não ser que você instancie a classe pelo nome ou faça um cast, como você fez no exemplo.

O que você quer fazer está mais parecendo uma especialização da classe com um método específico, que nesse caso seria uma herança, não a utilização de uma interface.

Comment: na verdade eu não estava pensando na especialização de subclasses não. Estava focado na implementação de uma interface mesmo. A ideia da especialização surgiu como um meio de tentar resolver um problema de planejamento (ou a falta dele) na criação da interface.