# Qual a diferença entre Abstração e Implementação?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre `Abstração` e `Implementação`, e como isso se aplica na prática!

Comment: Tem um contexto? A dúvida surgiu porque? Na forma atual parece que está perguntando qual é a diferença entre uma laranja e uma galinha. Aí se você me disser que está querendo comer um deles e quer saber o que é mais saudável fica mais fácil responder. Você está falando de um método abstrato ou de um método implementado?

Comment: @bigown obrigado pela pergunta, é que estou iniciando em OOP e vejo vários videos o pessoal falando, programe para Abstração e não para Implementação. E é só, não fala mais nada. Se puder editar a pergunta para que fique dentro do contexto de programar e responde-la eu agradeço. E muita coisa aprendi lendo suas respostas aqui no SOPT.

Comment: Acho que está querendo saber sobre isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101.

Comment: @bigown Valeu pelo link e obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstração é a habilidade de concentrar nos aspectos essenciais de um contexto qualquer, ignorando características menos importantes ou acidentais. Em modelagem orientada a objetos, uma classe é uma abstração de entidades existentes no domínio do sistema de software.

Por exemplo, imaginamos a abstração referente a classe Animais. Há várias entidades na classe Animais como Anfíbios, Répteis e Mamíferos que são também sub-classes da classe Animais, onde há objetos que contêm cada sub-classe como Ser-humano, Jacaré e outros.

Uma classe abstrata é desenvolvida para representar entidades e conceitos abstratos. A classe abstrata é sempre uma superclasse que não possui instâncias. Ela define um modelo (template) para uma funcionalidade e fornece uma implementação incompleta - a parte genérica dessa funcionalidade - que é compartilhada por um grupo de classes derivadas. Cada uma das classes derivadas, completa a funcionalidade da classe abstrata adicionando um comportamento específico. [(WIKIPÉDIA)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

A implementação, é o trabalho mesmo, escrever o código, enfim. O que o pessoal quer falar é que você precisa planejar, como o sistema irá se comportar em diferentes situações utilizando os objetos, ao invés de sair escrevendo o código sem pensar na abstração dos problemas.

Exemplo meio grotesco, aproveitando o gancho dos Animais demonstrado no wikipédia:

Não foi pensado na abstração dos problemas, e enfim... apenas implementado:

```
        public class Boi
        {
            public Boi()
            {
                Familia = "mamiferos";
                SubFamilia = "bovinos";
            }
            public string Familia { get; set; }
            public string SubFamilia { get; set; }
            public void Som()
            {
                //Mugir
            }
        }
        public class Cachorro
        {
            public Cachorro()
            {
                Familia = "mamiferos";
                SubFamilia = "caninos";
            }
            public string Familia { get; set; }
            public string SubFamilia { get; set; }
            public void Som()
            {
                //Latir
            }
        }

        private void Programa()
        {
            string animal = "boi";

            if (animal == "boi")
            {
                Boi boi = new Boi();
                boi.Som();
            }
            else
            {
                Cachorro dog = new Cachorro();
                dog.Som();
            }
        }
```

Agora com o mínimo de planejamento dos objetos, ficaria assim:

```
   public interface IAnimal
   {
       public void Som();
       public string Familia;
       public string SubFamilia;
   }

    public class Mamifero : IAnimal
    {
        public Mamifero()
        {
            Familia = "mamifero";
        }

        public string Familia { get; set; }
        public string SubFamilia { get; set; }
        public virtual void Som()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Boi : Mamifero
    {
        public Boi() : base()
        {
            SubFamilia = "bovinos";
        }

        public override void Som()
        {
            //mugir
        }
    }

    public class Cachorro : Mamifero
    {
        public Cachorro() : base()
        {
            SubFamilia = "caninos";

        }

        public override void Som()
        {
            //Latir
        }
    }

    public void Programa()
    {

        IAnimal animal;
        string animalEscolhido = "cachorro";

        if (animalEscolhido == "cachorro")
        {
            animal = new Cachorro();
        }
        else
        {
            animal = new Boi();
        }

        animal.Som();

    }
```

Dessa forma, na hora de implementar outros animais, toda a estrutura anterior de mamífero e animal, já estaria implementada, você não precisaria escrever toda essas propriedades novamente. Essa parte já terá sido abstraída.
Em um exemplo pequeno, parece compensador a primeira forma, mas tente aplicar esses conceitos a algo grande...

Desculpa o exemplo, espero que te ajude, mas não sou professor e a didática é péssima.