# Utilizando interfaces para classes de domínio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, herança, interface

É uma boa pratica fazer o uso de interfaces para classe de domínio? Tenho alguma vantagem fazendo isso? Se sim, qual?

Exemplo:

```
public interface IAuditoria
{
    long AuditoriaID { get; set; }
    string Descricao { get; set; }
    string SistemaOperacional { get; set; }
    string ResolucaoTela { get; set; }
    string ModeloDevice { get; set; }
    string Navegador { get; set; }
    string IPInternet { get; set; }
    string Geolocalizacao { get; set; }
    DateTime DataAuditoria { get; set; }
}

public class Auditoria : Entities.Bases.EntityBase, Entities.Interfaces.IAuditoria
{
    public Auditoria()
    {

    }

    #region Properties

    public long AuditoriaID { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string SistemaOperacional { get; set; }
    public string ResolucaoTela { get; set; }
    public string ModeloDevice { get; set; }
    public string Navegador { get; set; }
    public string IPInternet { get; set; }
    public string Geolocalizacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAuditoria { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nao vejo muito sentido em utilizar uma interface em classe de dominio, segue link que pode te ajudar bastante https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107524/como-e-quando-usar-interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Criar por criar sem um motivo não tem vantagem. Em tudo o que for fazer, tudo mesmo, até colocar uma espaço em branco no código precisa achar uma motivação.

Por isso que sempre falo para as pessoas largarem mão dessa coisa de boa práticas. Na prática elas servem para as pessoas seguiram receitas de bolo sem pensarem no que estão fazendo.

Consegue achar um motivo?

Eu posso dizer um: ter uma abstração para poder aceitar um tipo genérico e o concreto ser diferente em cada situação. É o chamado [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por que?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).

Precisa ter essa abstração?

Se não precisa ter essa generalidade, não vejo porque fazer.

Existe um caso que as pessoas dizem para fazer mesmo que o seu domínio não necessite, que é o tal do teste. Sem isso fica um pouco mais complicado testar outras coisas sem poder trocar a implementação. É questionável se vale a pena complicar o *design* concreto só para **facilitar** o teste.

Ainda assim, precisará trocar a implementação para poder fazer um teste melhor?

Continuo achando que não precisa.

Não é o que fazer que importa, é saber porque fazer.

Comment: Como você disse acabei seguinto boas práticas, na verdade me veio a cabeça fazer essa pergunta aqui, devido a não ver a necessidade de criar tudo isso. Mas em questão fiquei com a dúvida se isso poderia ou não me ajudar em algo futuro, como testes, entre outras coisas.

Answer (score 1):

A vantagem da interface é usar os seus comportamentos, independente do tipo do objeto.

Exemplo.

```
interface IAnimal{
        void Respira();
}
class Cachorro : IAnimal
{
 void Respira()
 {
 //Respira de um jeito
 }
}

class Gato : IAnimal
{ 
  void Respira()
  {
     //Respira de outro um jeito
  }
}
```

Se vc tiver uma lista do tipo da interface e percorrer ela, mesmo que os objetos colocados nela sejam diferentes, você terá a vantagem de chamar eles.
Já em uma classe de domínio, que só serve para manter o "design" dos dados... não se tem uma vantagem clara disso, talvez tenha, dependendo da sua interpretação sobre o problema.

Talvez seja interessante para manter uma organização e possivelmente ajudar em algo mais pra frente, porém, por mero capricho, não consigo achar uma justificativa. Vale a pena um debate.