# Java - Interface

Tags: java, interface, polimorfismo

Estava estudando interface e me surgiu uma dúvida no código abaixo:

```
public class TesteGerente {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

            Autenticavel referencia = new Cliente();

            Gerente g1 = new Gerente();
            g1.setNome("Marco");
            g1.setCpf("235568413");
            g1.setSalario(5000.0);

            System.out.println(g1.getNome());
            System.out.println(g1.getCpf());
            System.out.println(g1.getSalario());
            System.out.println(g1.getBonificacao());
   }
}
```

A parte do `new Cliente` usando como referência a interface que ele assina (`Autenticavel referencia = new Cliente()`) , qual seria a real vantagem de criar o objeto usando esse tipo de referência, e se muda algo no desenvolvimento do código ?

Comment: Além da duplicada sugerida acima, tem essas que também podem ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/112052

Comment: Nesse caso nenhuma, exemplos artificiais de uso não demonstram vantagens de uso.