# A implementação de uma interface faz parte do pilar de encapsulamento ou herança?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, herança, interface, encapsulamento

*A implementação de uma interface faz parte do pilar de encapsulamento ou herança da POO?*

Até onde sei o encapsulamento desrespeita a visibilidade dos atributos e métodos contidos em uma classe, já a herança é abstração de uma classe para que possamos estender-la para demais classes. Não sei onde a interface se encaixa nesses dois...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Encapsulamento** se refere a colocar tudo junto em uma cápsula, no mesmo local, então estritamente o mecanismo de interface em si não tem a ver com isso.

Porém você pode interpretar de alguma forma que tem relação no sentido que os comportamentos que serão criados para atender os contratos da interface estarão encapsulados no objeto, em oposição a ter um objeto ou funções em outro local para atender essas demandas.

Portanto não é tão simples responder isso, cabe interpretação, mas estritamente o mecanismo da interface é só para estabelecer contratos, nada a ver com orientação a objeto de forma direta.

A **herança** em si de forma completa também não ocorre na interface, porém a interface é uma forma de criar uma herança de tipo, ou seja, você dizer que um objeto terá uma capacidade e a interface funcionará como uma forma taxonômica de indicar uma generalização, que é o que também o que a herança faz. Mas é bom ficar claro que a interface, pura, já que existem linguagens que deram funcionalidades extras para interfaces, não herda os comportamentos dos contratos, e mesmo as linguagens que possuem interfaces mais poderosas não aceitam herança de estado. Portanto a herança clássica não é usada pela interface, mas novamente, podemos dizer que há alguma relação porque é possível usar o mecanismo para estabelecer um herança múltipla em certo ponto de vista, só considerando o tipo.

Encapsulamento não é sobre visibilidade de campos ([não atributos, esse termo é ensinado errado por aí](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)), o conceito de deixar a visibilidade privada é chamado de *information hiding*. E de certa forma é um jeito de criar uma abstração.

Toda afirmação sobre encapsulamento está esquisita, por isso é até difícil dizer o quanto ela está errada.

Herança não é uma abstração, esses conceitos são diferentes. É possível ter uma classe abstrata para fazer herança, mas o termo abstrato ali é um pouco diferente, é só dizer que aquilo é uma forma geral aproximada de como o objeto deve ser, não é a definição completa do objeto.

Em PHP a interface é um bicho esquisito, ou era, porque ele é um mecanismo de contrato e PHP é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica e fraca, ou seja, ela não liga para contratos. Isso até esta mudando, a linguagem tem adicionado mecanismos de contratos pelo menos na sintaxe da linguagem. É esquisito uma linguagem nascer com uma filosofia e dar um cavalo de pau e fazer o oposto depois.

Posso te dizer? OOP é mais complexo do que as pessoas imaginam e poucas pessoas fazem certo. As pessoas dão muito valor para algo que elas nem entendem. Se elas fizessem OOP do jeito certo o código seria até complexo demais, algumas pessoas que tentam realmente tendem fazer código mais complexos do que deveria. OOP é útil, mas até entender tudo, ganhar experiência, porque é isso que conta, vai muito tempo, demanda muito esforço. A maioria das pessoas só querem dizer que fazem OOP porque isso é estar na moda.

Leia mais sobre em [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).