# Como melhorar um programa em java com relação a sua coesão e baixo acoplamento

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo o programa em anexo, mas preciso que ele tenha alta coesão e baixo acoplamento. Estava pensando em criar uma classe apenas para gerar a apresentação dos resultados, mas o problema é que fica muito acoplado pelo fato dos cálculos da área e do perímetro entre retângulo, quadrado e circunferência serem diferentes. Estou em dúvida se realizei da melhor forma. Gostaria de sugestões e com algum exemplo, ainda estou iniciando e às vezes tenho dificuldade de entender o que me dizem.

```
public class BrincandoComAsFigurasGeometricas {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
        //Inicializando as variaveis
        String nomeRetangulo = "Retângulo";
        int alturaDoRetangulo = 2;
        int larguraDoRetangulo = 4;
        
        String nomeQuadrado = "Quadrado"; 
        int ladoDoQuadrado = 2;
        
        String nomeCirculo = "Circulo";
        int raioDoCirculo = 3;
        
        //Criando Retângulo
        try {
            Quadrilatero retangulo = new Quadrilatero(nomeRetangulo, alturaDoRetangulo, larguraDoRetangulo);
            retangulo.calcularArea();
            retangulo.calcularPerimetro();
            System.out.println("Retângulo: ");
            System.out.println(retangulo.mostrarArea());
            System.out.println(retangulo.mostrarPerimetro());
            System.out.println(retangulo.mostrarCaracteristicas());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        
        
        try {//Criando Quadrado
            
            Quadrilatero quadrado = new Quadrilatero(nomeQuadrado, ladoDoQuadrado, ladoDoQuadrado);
            quadrado.calcularArea();
            quadrado.calcularPerimetro();
            System.out.println("\nQuadrado: ");
            System.out.println(quadrado.mostrarArea());
            System.out.println(quadrado.mostrarPerimetro());
            System.out.println(quadrado.mostrarCaracteristicas());
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        
        try {//Criando Circulo
            
            Circulo circulo = new Circulo(nomeCirculo, raioDoCirculo);
            circulo.calcularArea();
            circulo.calcularPerimetro();
            System.out.println("\nCirculo: ");
            System.out.println(circulo.mostrarArea());
            System.out.println(circulo.mostrarPerimetro());
            System.out.println(circulo.mostrarCaracteristicas());       

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

    }

}
    public interface InterfaceFormas{
        
        public int calcularArea();
        
        public int calcularPerimetro(); 
        
        public String mostrarArea();
        
        public String mostrarPerimetro();

        public String mostrarCaracteristicas();     
    }
public class Circulo implements InterfaceFormas{
    String nome;
    int raio;
    
    public Circulo(String nome, int raio) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.raio = raio;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getRaio() {
        return raio;
    }

    public void setRaio(int raio) {
        this.raio = raio;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int calcularArea() {     
        return (int) (2 * 3.14 * getRaio() * getRaio());
    }
    
    @Override
    public int calcularPerimetro() {
        return (int) (2 * 3.14 * getRaio());
    }
    
    @Override
    public String mostrarArea() {
        String toString = "";

        if (getRaio() > 0) { 
            toString +=  "A área deste " + getNome() + " é: " + calcularArea() + "\n";
        } else {
            toString += "O valor que vc forneceu não representa nenhuma figura geométrica conhecida!\n";
        }
        return toString;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String mostrarPerimetro() {
        String toString = "";

        if (getRaio() > 0) { 
            toString +=  "O perimetro deste " + getNome() + " é: " + calcularPerimetro() + "\n";
        } else {
            toString += "O valor que vc forneceu não representa nenhuma figura geométrica conhecida!\n";
        }
        return toString;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String mostrarCaracteristicas(){
        String toString = "";
        if (getRaio() > 0) {
            toString +=  "O circulo criado tem raio de tamanho: " + getRaio() + "\n"; 
        } else {
            toString += "O valor que vc forneceu não representa nenhuma figura geométrica conhecida!\n";
        }
        return toString;
    }

}


public class Quadrilatero implements InterfaceFormas{
    
    private String nome;
    private int altura;
    private int comprimento;
    
    
    public Quadrilatero(String nome, int altura, int comprimento) {
        this.setNome(nome);
        this.setAltura(altura);
        this.setComprimento(comprimento);
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }


    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }


    public int getAltura() {
        return altura;
    }


    public void setAltura(int altura) {
        this.altura = altura;
    }


    public int getComprimento() {
        return comprimento;
    }


    public void setComprimento(int comprimento) {
        this.comprimento = comprimento;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int calcularArea() {     
        return getAltura() * getComprimento();      
    }
    
    @Override
    public int calcularPerimetro() {
        return 2 * getAltura() + 2 * getComprimento();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String mostrarArea() {
        String toString = "";

        if (getAltura() > 0 && getComprimento() > 0) { 
            toString +=  "A área deste " + getNome() + " é: " + calcularArea() + "\n";
        } else {
            toString += "O valor que vc forneceu não representa nenhuma figura geométrica conhecida!\n";
        }
        return toString;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String mostrarPerimetro() {
        String toString = "";

        if (getAltura() > 0 && getComprimento() > 0) { 
            toString +=  "O perimetro deste " + getNome() + " é: " + calcularPerimetro() + "\n";
        } else {
            toString += "O valor que vc forneceu não representa nenhuma figura geométrica conhecida!\n";
        }
        return toString;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String mostrarCaracteristicas() {
        String toString = "";
        toString +=  "O " + getNome() + " criado tem altura de tamanho: " + getAltura() + 
                " e largura de tamanho: " + getComprimento() + "\n"; 
        return toString;
    }   

    
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { throw new Exception(e);}` - isso não faz o menor sentido. Se vai encapsular a exceção em outra, deveria usar uma classe mais específica. Mas como é `Exception`, basicamente esse `catch` captura qualquer exceção e não faz sentido criar outra... Aliás, se for pra fazer isso, melhor nem ter `try`/`catch`...

Answer (score 2):

Quando você trabalha em uma abstração (por exemplo, uma classe), deve garantir que sua interface (me referindo ao seu conjunto de métodos públicos) possua um conjunto coeso de operações, isto é, que elas tenham completude no sentido de se atingir um objetivo comum e não apresentem nenhuma parte dispensável ou destoante. É isso que se chama de [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/357).

Por tabela, o conjunto de campos internos deve ser coeso/coerente entre si e com essas operações também, pois elas operam sobre esse estado interno.

Coesão tem a ver com coerência. O conjunto todo que compõe a abstração tem que ser coerente. Um objeto da classe `Pessoa` que imprime seus dados ou acessa um banco de dados não está sendo coerente.

No caso de formas geométricas convexas, operações de `getArea()` e `getPerimetro()` podem fazer parte desse conjunto coeso de operações pertencentes a uma abstração `FormaGeometrica`, pois são comuns a todas as formas geométricas convexas (note que não estou mandando imprimir esses valores, apenas retornando-os. Imprimir não é papel da forma geométrica e reduziria a coesão da mesma. Faça isso externamente às classes).

Campos internos que fazem sentido para suas subclasses são aqueles que têm relação com essas operações não-privadas mencionadas, ou seja, são utilizados na implementação das mesmas (`raio` no caso de `Círculo`, `comprimento` e `largura` no caso de `Retângulo`, etc). Um objeto, em orientação a objetos, é a combinação de estado e operações que manipulam esse estado.

Pode-se dizer que um método `mostrarCaracteristicas()` tem relação com essas operações e portanto preserva a coesão, mas por outro lado se ele imprimir em uma saída de texto estará violando-a. Ele pode ser definido como uma operação abstrata da superclasse ou interface comum e retornar uma `String` descrevendo o objeto, por exemplo um `toString()` (que inclusive já existe na classe `Object` do Java e pode ser sobrescrita).

*En passant*:

- Um objeto deve ou ser construído completamente válido ou então não ser construído (por exemplo, seu construtor pode lançar uma exceção caso receba um argumento inválido). Então só deve fazer sentido que ele retorne uma `String` de descrição válida, pois deverá obrigatoriamente estar bem construído.
- *Getters* e *setters* não são obrigatórios. Se não precisam ser utilizados, podem muito bem ser omitidos da interface pública.

Quando se aumenta a coesão, o acoplamento tende a diminuir.

Duas coisas que ajudam a reduzir o acoplamento são [programar voltado para a interface e não para a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/357) e o princípio da inversão de dependência: depender de abstrações e não de concretudes.

Por exemplo, faça um código cliente das formas geométricas depender da superclasse/interface `FormaGeometrica` e não de `Retângulo`, `Círculo`, etc.

E, caso essas classes dependessem de alguma outra (pela definição das mesmas não é para terem dependências, mas vamos supor que dependessem), essas dependências deveriam ser abstrações, quando aplicável, e não concretudes.

Em um exemplo "tirado da cartola", poderiam por exemplo depender de uma classe abstrata ou interface `ContextoGrafico` passada para as mesmas e não diretamente de suas subclasses `ContextoGraficoCartesiano` ou `ContextoGraficoPolar`.

Uma terceira coisa que ajuda a reduzir o acoplamento é aplicar padrões GRASP às suas classes.