# Exemplo prático List e ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, declaração-de-variável

Estou a criar uma lista de `Estudantes`, porém deparo me com a seguinte situação. No ponto 2 dá me erro porque diz que tenho de tirar o Estudante dentro da List mas quando faço o ponto 1 já está correto.

Suspostamente o objetivo é ter o main como o ponto 2. E dentro do `ArrayList` não tem nada. O que me aconselham? A fazer como o ponto 1?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    (1) ArrayList<Estudante> lista = new ArrayList<Estudante>(); //assim dá mas com List e arraylist nao da porque?
    (2) List <Estudante> lista1 = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

mesmo se fizer assim:

```
    List<Estudante> lista1 = new ArrayList<Estudante>();
```

O `List` fica a dar erro:

> The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments Estudante

A minha classe estudante apenas tem o numero e o nome:

```
public class Estudante {
private int numero;
private String nome;

public Estudante(int numero, String nome){
    this.numero = numero;
    this.nome = nome;
}
```

Comment: [**ArrayList x List**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73633/arraylist-x-list?rq=1)

Comment: @diegofm ai ja tinha entendido. Mas nesse exemplo é igual! E não dá sequer.

Comment: Não, não é igual, no `ArrayList` do segundo exemplo não está sendo informado o tipo de dado que a lista vai guardar.

Comment: mas mesmo se meter o tipo de dados não dá. vou meter um exemplo

Comment: Como eu demonstrei na resposta, o que está na edição não ocorre de fato. Se estiver ocorrendo sugiro criar um [mcve] para demonstrar isso.

Comment: O problema não é no código apresentado aqui,  veja um exemplo idêntico ao seu, utilizando o código da resposta do @bigown : http://ideone.com/9ZJiTD

Comment: Rapaz, o exemplo 2 tem que funcionar, se eu fosse chutar sem ver o codigo completo, eu diria que você está importando List da biblioteca errada. Tem que ser de java.util...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só colocar o objeto que será usado na construção do objeto. Só pode omitir se a declaração do tipo da variável for igual à construção do objeto:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Estudante> lista = new ArrayList<Estudante>();
        List<Estudante> lista1 = new ArrayList<Estudante>();
        ArrayList<Estudante> lista2 = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

class Estudante {}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/njDIu5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pgyzjgud-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/ArrayList.java).

Não esqueça de fazer o `import`.

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente o problema é o `import` incorreto. Você deve estar importando a classe `List` do pacote de interface gráfica. Basta trocar:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

Por:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Seu código funcionará normalmente.

#### [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/4rkU9W)