# Premissas para um software testável

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, testes, testes-funcionais, testes-de-unidade

Tomando como base o desenvolvimento em linguagem orientada a objetos, quais seriam as premissas para que o software tenha uma testabilidade robusta (cobertura e facilidade de teste) ?

Comment: Qual seria a definição de *testabilidade robusta*?

Comment: Cobertura e facilidade dos teste.

Comment: Obrigado por aceitar a resposta, mas algumas vezes é interessante esperar um dia ou dois para dar a chance de outros usuários fazerem melhor, daí você não perde pontos por trocar a resposta aceita por outra. :D

Comment: Pois é, quem dera fosse como no fórum gringo onde temos dezenas de respostas e, as vezes, são até bloqueadas. :) 

Quando gosto da resposta eu normalmente já marco como aceita, não quero cometer a injustiça de cair no esquecimento. Se tiver outras respostas legais terão meu voto.

Comment: A resposta está ótimo. Acho que nem precisa se preocupar. Só acrescentaria que é importante usar as ferramentas de testes e `coverage` existentes para cada linguagem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

Existe muitos tipos diferentes de testes em diferentes níveis de abstração do sistema, desde testes unitários até o teste de aceitação do usuário. Veja mais detalhes [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19196/227).

A testabilidade é a capacidade do software de ser testado em todos aqueles níveis, sendo maior quanto mais fácil é implementar e executar o teste e menor quanto mais difícil é se fazer isto.

Porém, contudo, entretanto, todavia não existe um método ou conjunto de métodos que efetivamente possa garantir a qualidade de um software.

## Complexidade intrínseca

A primeira e mais forte razão da dificuldade de testar exaustivamente um software consiste em que um software é uma entidade abstrata e extremamente complexa por natureza. Troque um bit dentre os dados e o comportamento seguinte é imprevisível.

A quantidade de variáveis (não confundir com as variáveis declaradas no código) quando um sistema executa leva a um número quase incalculável de possibilidades de execução, sendo humanamente impossível testar ou mesmo definir todas essas possibilidades.

## Qualidade é subjetiva

A outra razão, que assombra testadores em todo o mundo, é que qualidade é uma métrica extremamente subjetiva.

Um sistema pode ter 100% de cobertura em testes e ainda assim não atender as necessidades do usuário. Por outro lado, um sistema praticamente sem testes e cheio de bugs pode ser mais útil que o primeiro.

## Melhor não testar nada

Brincadeira. Não é porque algo é difícil e complicado que não devemos fazer.

Claro que devemos testar software, sempre, mas devemos fazer isto conscientemente sem confiar cegamente em alguma biblioteca, framework ou metodologia.

## Como criar código orientado a objetos com boa testabilidade

Se tratarmos do ponto de visto do código, esquecendo por um momento os testes de mais alto nível como integração ou de usuário, na verdade, não existe muito segredo.

Embora existam diversas técnicas e boas práticas que possam ser observadas, vou me ater ao que considero ser o ponto central.

### Divisão de responsabilidade entre as classes

Se cada classe/objeto do sistema tiver uma responsabilidade única e bem definida, será muito fácil testar cada uma individualmente.

Simples assim.

Porém, nem sempre é fácil atingir tal ideal num sistema complexo, então devemos expandir um pouco este universo para outros princípios importantes.

### [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Considero os princípios conhecidos como *SOLID* os mais elementares e importantes ao projetar e codificar sistemas.

Também não vou me estender sobre cada um, pois existem livros inteiros sobre o assunto e algumas questões aqui mesmo no SO, tais como:

- [Princípio aberto/fechado - como entender isso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15645/227)
- [Dúvida teórica - Interface, responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10313/227)

> (se alguém achar mais, pode acrescentar aqui)

É interessante quando se estuda esses princípios, pois algumas vezes parecem que todos falam da mesma coisa. Pode ser confuso, mas ao mesmo tempo faz todo sentido, pois todos convergem para o mesmo fim.

Por exemplo, o **princípio da responsabilidade única** facilita usar e testar uma classe porque ela tem um propósito bem definido, menos variáveis de uso, portanto, menos possibilidades de problemas.

O **princípio aberto/fechado** nos ajuda a não precisar alterar código existente, o que evita retrabalho ao testar e novas combinações de teste no código existente.

O **princípio da substituição de Liskov** trabalha em conjunto com o aberto/fechado, tornando possível estender as classes sem modificar as classes existentes e sem surpresas desagradáveis, pois seguindo-o você deve garantir que as novas subclasses possam ser usadas sem quebrar as funcionalidades existentes.

O **princípio da segregação das interfaces** tem muito a ver com responsabilidade única, evitando que uma interface apresenta comportamentos desconexos e, portanto, seja de difícil uso e testes.

Por último, o **princípio da inversão de dependências** ou inversão de controle diminui o acoplamento entre as classes e permite que possamos testar os objetos de forma isolada usando mocks, stubs ou seja lá o que for, retirando da classe a responsabilidade de encontrar suas dependências.

## Considerações

Testes não são uma bala de prata para a qualidade de um sistema, mas são necessários na medida em que eles nos ajudam a determinar se o sistema *faz o que deveria estar fazendo*.

Em nível de código, um sistema orientado a objetos cujas classes são coesas e fracamente acopladas, cada uma com responsabilidades simples e bem definidas garante um boa testabilidade em testes unitários e também de integração.

Nos demais níveis, diferentes técnicas podem ser aplicadas, mas isto independe do paradigma de programação.